# When I add a YouTube video in an iframe to a grid, everything moves over and is compressed and the video is not on the page

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm using a Grid to build a page. I've been having some trouble with the formatting, as I'm not very familiar with the grid system in general. I thought I'd solved the issue, but now when I try to add a YouTube video in an iframe, everything jumps over as if the video is in a second column that doesn't exist.

I've tried placing the iframe in different sections. When I added it before it did work, so I know the link itself is formatted correctly. I then took it out to add more content and now it doesn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/amandathedev/pen/zyEyze

This is the relevant section:

```
      <p class="text mx-auto">
        Brush calligraphy is a craft that combines hand lettering and
        traditional calligraphy. Sometimes called 'modern calligraphy,' it
        is a skill that almost anyone can learn with some practice.
      </p>
      <div class="video-responsive">
        <iframe
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sBoVGqiSzr4"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
```

I think I might be formatting the grid incorrectly, but I followed videos and tutorials. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm a little confused about the issue you're having. I did notice you have a `height: 0;` on `.video-responsive`. When I remove that, the video does appear in the third column.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thank you! I'm trying to have it in the same column as the main content. I'm actually not sure why there are three columns.